# Связь расширения для браузера и активной страницы

Tags: javascript, html, opera, extension

Пробую сделать расширение для браузера и столкнулся с одним непонятным моментом. Как сделать, чтобы скрипт мог видеть сразу и popup расширения, и активную страницу в браузере? Для примера: в расширении поле для ввода и кнопка. Вводим текст в поле, нажимаем кнопку и в какой-то элемент на странице в браузере вставляем то, что ввели. Прошу дать хотя бы наводку.
P.s.: расширение делаю для оперы, если это важно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться несколькими вариантами:

- самый простой, но не всегда удобный, комбинировать отправку/прием сообщений

  - [runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) - отправить сообщение, но только не скрипту контента, например из popup в background
  - [tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage) - отправить сообщение табу
  - [runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage) - устанавливает слушателя сообщений
- немножко сложнее, но максимально гибкий

  - [runtime.connect](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-connect) - из всех зависимых скриптов(контент,popup, и т.п.) запрашиваем соединение с background
  - [runtime.onConnect](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onConnect) - в background принимаем соединиения
  - ... далее, в этом варианте, используем для связи долгоживущий порт, по которому очень легко передавать/получать сообщения в обе стороны.

PS: Расширение лучше делать и тестировать в Chrome, а после установить его в Оперу.

Comment: А нет разницы в написании расширения на хром и оперу?

Comment: @Mr.Code разницы то наверное нет. Но как-то Опера, у меня, через раз выводила console в background-скрипте, что очень неудобно при исследовании некоторых примеров - все время кажется что где-то ошибся. С Хромом таких проблем не наблюдал. Хотя сами расширения адекватно работают в двух браузерах. Может сейчас они все исправили, это было около 2-х лет назад.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь